# Proper way to use Action in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working a color guessing game. I have an action called `generateColors()` that generate 9 colors and an answer will be randomly chosen from those 9 colors. My `App.js` renders `Header.js` and `BoxGrid.js`.

Currently I call `generateColors()` in `BoxGrid.js`. What is the right way to pass answer to `Header.js`? Should I call `generateColors()` in `App.js` instead?

`BoxGrid.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Box from '../components/box';
import { generateColors } from '../actions';

class BoxGrid extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.generateColors();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="grid">
                    {this.props.colors.map((color)=>{
                        return <Box key={color} color={color}/>
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapState({colors}){
    return {colors};
}

export default connect(mapState,{generateColors})(BoxGrid);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how the application looks like so I may be wrong.

Because you're using Redux, just save the answer to your Redux store, and connect `Header` to the store (or just connect `App` and pass the props down to `Header`, both are fine)

Personally I'd prefer to put that action in App.js in this case, so the `BoxGrid` doesn't need do care about any application logic, just renders the UI. But I think this is just personal tastes and there is no correct answer.

You can see the faq of Redux doc here:

> Should I only connect my top component, or can I connect multiple components in my tree?

http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `answer` you mean that the user is picking a color, and you want to pass that user input from one component to another. There are a couple of ways to do this. You could pass down a function from `App` as a prop to the component below, and when that function is called, it sets local state within `App`, which is also passed down to child components:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        answer: null
     }
  }

  updateAnswer(answer) {
     this.setState({ answer: answer })
  }

  render () {
     return <div>
        <Header answer={this.state.answer} />
        <BoxGrid answer={this.state.answer} updateAnswer={this.updateAnswer.bind(this)} />
     </div>
  }
}
```

Then, when `BoxGrid` calls `this.props.updateAnswer(answer)` it will get passed to header. This doesn't use the Redux store.

The other way is to use the Redux store, and call an action. If you are sharing data between several components this probably makes more sense than using local state as above. Very similar to what you have already posted, you can just connect any component and grab the global state. Instead of setting local state in the `App` component, you would have an `answer` reducer, which would look like:

```
function answer (state = { answer: null }, action) {
  if (action.type === 'saveAnswer') {
    return { answer: action.answer }
  }
}
```

And a saveAnswer action creator like:

```
function saveAnswer (answer) {
  return {
     type: 'saveAnswer',
     answer: answer
  }
}
```

Then if you connect you `App` component with `mapStateToProps`, function you just grab the answer out of the store and return it as props, which can be passed down to any child component. As your hierarchy gets more complex, you can choose to connect any child component, but if you just have 3 total components, it probably makes more sense to just connect `App` and pass down data from the store as props.